# Error 1001. The specified service already exists. Existing service can't removed

Tags: c#, service

I tried to re-install my existing service and it returns an error "Error 1001. The specified service already exists"

I have tried the "sc delete servicename" but it does not work. Any inputs on this?

Comment: Did you stop the service before you tried to delete it?

Answer (score 15):

The best solution I have found to "Error 1001. The specified service already exists" when installing/upgrading/repairing a Windows Service project is to modify the ProjectInstaller.Designer.cs.

Add the following line to the beginning of InitializeComponent() which will trigger an event before your current installer tries to install the service again. In this event we will uninstall the service if it already exists.

Be sure to add the following to the top of the cs file to implement the following namespaces...

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ServiceProcess;
```

Then use the following as show below in the example...

```
this.BeforeInstall += new
System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventHandler(ProjectInstaller_BeforeInstall);
```

Example:

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{

    this.BeforeInstall += new System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventHandler(ProjectInstaller_BeforeInstall);

    this.serviceProcessInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceProcessInstaller();
    this.serviceInstaller1 = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceInstaller();
    // 
    // serviceProcessInstaller1
    // 
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem;
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Password = null;
    this.serviceProcessInstaller1.Username = null;
    // 
    // serviceInstaller1
    // 
    this.serviceInstaller1.Description = "This is my service name description";
    this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName = "MyServiceName";
    this.serviceInstaller1.StartType = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceStartMode.Automatic;
    // 
    // ProjectInstaller
    // 
    this.Installers.AddRange(new System.Configuration.Install.Installer[]{
            this.serviceProcessInstaller1,
            this.serviceInstaller1
        }
    );
}
```

The below code called by the event will then uninstall the service if it exists.

```
void ProjectInstaller_BeforeInstall(object sender, System.Configuration.Install.InstallEventArgs e)
{
    List<ServiceController> services = new List<ServiceController>(ServiceController.GetServices());

    foreach (ServiceController s in services)
    {
        if (s.ServiceName == this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName)
        {
            ServiceInstaller ServiceInstallerObj = new ServiceInstaller();
            ServiceInstallerObj.Context = new System.Configuration.Install.InstallContext();
            ServiceInstallerObj.Context = Context;
            ServiceInstallerObj.ServiceName = "MyServiceName";
            ServiceInstallerObj.Uninstall(null);

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer but GetServices() does not contain the ToList() method, AKA ServiceController type does not support it.  Instead use List<ServiceController> services = new List<ServiceController>(ServiceController.GetServices());  - Correction added to answer as well as other things that need to be done.

Comment: I see you already edited my answer but the ToList() is part of Linq and does work. Obviously you would have to use System.Linq in your project.

Comment: Sorry CathalMF, didn't know that.  Just trying to get it to work out of the box with the code provided.  Thanks for the clarification.  ;)

Comment: No worries, you way is simpler and will work right out of the box. I probably should have specified that Linq was required.

Comment: Thank you. Best answer I have ever seen for "Error 1001" questions.

Comment: @CathalMF You saved my day buddy.. I have almost spent 2 days to resolve this issue. In addition to this code i had to remove InstallValidate action from InstallExecuteSequence table using Orca.

Comment: I've done this and I still get the 1001 error. I'm pretty sure the BeforeInstall code isn't even running.

Comment: Is there a reason you're setting the Context twice?

Comment: No, accidental.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to CathalMF answer, I also had to stop the service before uninstall by adding the line below to the code:

```
    if (s.ServiceName == this.serviceInstaller1.ServiceName)
    {
        if(s.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
           s.Stop();
        ....
    }
```